# Duda al configurar Dagger Hilt en mi proyecto

Tags: android, inyeccion-de-dependencias, dagger, hilt

deseo configurar Dagger Hilt en mi proyecto, siguiendo la guía oficial me indica que debo agregar el complemento de hilt-android-gradle-plugin en el build.gradle raíz de mi proyecto.

Sin embargo, mi archivo build.gradle a nivel proyecto es distinto y no sé cómo puedo agregarlo.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

ya que me indica que debe ir en la sección buildscript (pero no tengo esa sección)

```
buildscript {
    
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28-alpha'
    }
}
```

Si la agrego como en el ejemplo de la documentación me marca error.

Agrego mi build.gradle del módulo

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mc.com.dosftware.helloworl"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de poder configurar dagger hilt actualmente?

Answer (score 0):

Es extraño que no tengas un apartado de dependencias en tu archivo build.grade del proyecto, ¿será que no estás editando el archivo correcto?

Este es el esqueleto, más o menos de dicho archivo que debe estar en esta carpeta: **`...StudioProjects/TuProyecto/build.gradle`**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        //Aquí repositorios
    }


    dependencies {
        //Aquí dependencias
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Aquí lo que sea
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Si no tienes el apartado `dependencies` debes crearlo, por supuesto, y meter allí lo que indica la documentación (ese apartado irá dentro de `buildscript` si observas el esqueleto que te puse más arriba):

```
dependencies {
    // Otras posibles dependencias ...
    classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28-alpha'
}
```

Luego, en el archivo `build.gradle` de la aplicación, que debería estar en la carpeta: **`...StudioProjects/TuProyecto/app/build.gradle`** pones lo que te indica la documentación:

```
...
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
}
```

Eso ya depende, si usas Kotlin o no. Yo por ejemplo no uso Kotlin, y he puesto sólo esto para usar dagger-hilt:

```
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

// ...

dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"

}
```

Como dice la documentación, Hilt usa Java 8, por lo que deberás poner también esto, en tu archivo gradle del módulo de aplicación, situado, recuerda, en `app/build.gradle`:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Si no te funciona, edita la pregunta, poniendo lo que tienes en tus archivos `build.gradle`, recuerda que hablamos de **dos archivos**, uno situado en la raíz del proyecto, y otro situado dentro de la carpeta `app` del proyecto.